# PostgreSQL FTS for quoted xml tags - is it possible?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, xml

I use Pg FTS to text-search database containing some technical descriptions/comments. Which in particular happen to contain XML snippets. 
Those are amazingly difficult to find by XML tags. I found basic workaround (to find tags exactly-as-written) but look for suggestions how to improve.

**Default state**

```
CREATE TABLE mytab(id INTEGER, descr TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytab VALUES(1, 'Please create table');
INSERT INTO mytab VALUES(2, 'Please add <some-tag/> to config file');

SELECT id FROM mytab where descr @@ 'add';
    2
   (1 row)

SELECT id FROM mytab where descr @@ '<some-tag/>';
   (0 rows)

SELECT id FROM mytab where descr @@ 'some-tag';
   (0 rows)

SELECT ts_debug('add <some-tag/>');
   (asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",add,{english_stem},english_stem,{add})
   (blank,"Space symbols"," ",{},,)
   (tag,"XML tag",<some-tag/>,{},,)
```

**Finding tags as exactly-written**

I managed to improve things a little bit by:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION xmlfixed(COPY = english);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION xmlfixed ADD MAPPING FOR TAG WITH simple;

SELECT id FROM mytab WHERE TO_TSVECTOR('xmlfixed', descr) @@ TO_TSQUERY('xmlfixed', 'add');
      2
    (1 row)

SELECT id FROM mytab WHERE TO_TSVECTOR('xmlfixed', descr) @@ TO_TSQUERY('xmlfixed', '<some-tag/>');
      2
    (1 row)
```

but this works only if tag is written exactly. I still have

```
SELECT id FROM mytab WHERE TO_TSVECTOR('xmlfixed', descr) @@ TO_TSQUERY('xmlfixed', '<some-tag>');
    (0 rows)
SELECT id FROM mytab WHERE TO_TSVECTOR('xmlfixed', descr) @@ TO_TSQUERY('xmlfixed', 'some-tag');
    (0 rows)
```

(ok, ok, internally there were GIN indexes and reindex, but that's orthogonal)

**Looking for help**

Is there any way to configure this search so record 2 can be found when querying user asks for `some-tag`? Is it possible without writing new binary extension?

I suppose I could try implementing new custom dictionary which would strip <>/ characters, and use it together with simple as mapping for `tag` (codewise sth similar to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993032/custom-postgres-fts-dictionary, and above that `ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION xmlfixed ALTER MAPPING FOR TAG WITH xmlstripper, simple;`, where xmlstripper would be this new extension). Still, distributing new binary extension seems very difficult (if at all possible) at organizational level.

Mayhaps there is some other way?